# Como executar um script python que está localizado em outra máquina

Tags: python, apache, servidor

Tenho 2 raspberry e um computador windows que tem um servidor apache. Quero executar um script que está no servidor a partir desses 2 raspberry.

Eu digito na linha de comando:

```
sudo python3 192.168.0.8//teste/teste.py
```

mas vem a seguinte mensagem:

> python3: can't open file '192.168.0.8//teste/teste.py': [Errno 2] No such file or diretory

O que estou fazendo de errado ? Como chamar executar um script que está em um servidor ?

Comment: Em qual máquina o script deve rodar? No servidor ou no rasp?

Comment: não tem haver com permissão, só configurar o apache para exec arquivos .py.. assim como configura para java php django.. pode ter vários arquivos dentro ai só especificar localhost:porta/arq.py.. se você estiver na mesma rede local usando mesmo rotiador.

Answer (score 0):

O python não possui funcionalidade de execução remota. Você precisa "montar" a pasta remota e fornecer um caminho local para o python:

```
mkdir /pasta_local
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.8/compartilhamento/ /pasta_local
```

Então use essa pasta para acessar o servidor:

```
python3 /pasta_local/teste/teste.py
```

Uma outra forma é, se o script está sendo fornecido pelo apache, você baixar o script via http, usando `curl` ou `wget`, aí é só rodar.

```
curl http://192.168.0.8/teste.py -o teste.py
python3 teste.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Muito provável que isso é problema de privilégios, verifique se a pasta na qual está os arquivos tem permissão para administrador, caso não esteja com tais privilégios atribua e após isso reinicie o serviço e tente iniciar a página, caso não resolve, verifique se todas as bibliotecas do Python e assim como todos os recursos estão instalados no servidor para que não acha problemas.

Primeiramente você irá editar o arquivo sudoers com o seguinte comando:

vim /etc/sudoers ou gedit /etc/sudoers

e adicionar a seguinte linha nesse arquivo:

nomedousuário ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL

Desse modo tudo o que você executar no apache será como super usuário.

Comment: Olá João, obrigado pela rápida resposta. Mas meu servidor fica numa máquina que está rodando Windows 10 e não o Debian. Meu problema é chamar um script python (que está no servidor windows 10) a partir de um raspberry que está rodando Debian.

Comment: essa resposta não tem nenhuma relação com a mensagem de erro reportada.  Seria o caso se o erro tivesse a ver com os privilégios de SUDO, mas está longe de ser o caso.